# How to make PHP work with html5 when creating blackberry NATIVE app with blackberry websockets

Tags: html, blackberry

I have a simple html5 page and it has inline php script, any suggestions on how i can create the app to make it when use with blackberry websockets. 
eg. A native app that is writeen with html5.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is interpreted on a server with PHP installed, not the client (your phone, a browser, etc). You won't be able to use PHP in a native app, but you can use JavaScript. If you need some interactivity with the hardware on your phone, you can take a look into frameworks like [PhoneGap](https://www.phonegap.com), or maybe even something like [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/touch/)

Comment: Thanks.. I knew php couldnt work, but wanted confirmation to my theory. Thanks